# SQL Server - Enforcing uniqueness in one column depending on another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, constraints

Apologies if I get the terminology wrong. How do I define a constraint in MSSQL Server 2005 to enforce uniqueness in one column depending on another column?

E.g. considering the last two columns:

```
1    A    1
2    A    2
3    A    2 <- Disallow because '2' has already appeared alongside 'A'
4    B    1
5    B    2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE tTable
    (field1 CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
     field2 INT NOT NULL,
     UNIQUE (field1, field2)
)
```

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem. (If I am reading this right) in that row three will have unique field 1 and 2 but still fail

Comment: This does solve the problem.  When you try to insert the second ('A', 2) record, SQL stops you with a violation of a unique constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Create a unique constraint on the 2 columns ?

This is the most logical thing to do, since it seems that this one column is not unique, but the combination of the 2 columns must be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't need to be a primary key, all it needs to be is a unique composite index.